# Arithmetic on end() iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Let A be a `std::vector<double>`,

Is this well-defined?

```
if(!A.empty())
    std::vector<double>::iterator myBack = A.end() - 1;
```

Is the `end` iterator only good for equalities and inequalities checks? Or I can perform some pointer arithmetic as long as I remain in the container?

On my platform this code works. I'm wondering if this is portable.

Comment: This is fine and you can also use `A.rbegin()`.

Comment: It is *iterator* arithmetic. and it should be OK for bidirectional iterator (as `std::vector::iterator`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is perfectly valid as `vector::iterator` is a random access iterator. You can perform arithmetic operations on it and it is not platform dependent.

```
std::vector<double>::iterator it = A.end();
while (it != A.begin()){
    --it; //this will skip A.end() and loop will break after processing A.front()
    //do something with 'it'
}
```

But `A.end()` refers to theoretical past-the-end element, so it does not point to an element and thus shall not be dereferenced. So best practice is to use reverse iterator instead of decrementing end iterator.

```
for(std::vector<double>::reverse_iterator it = A.rbegin(); it != A.rend(); ++it) {
    //do something with 'it'
}
```

These two loops do the same thing, second is just understandable, cleaner way to do it.

Comment: The two loops are not identical, the first one doesn't iterate over `A.front()`.

Comment: But I don't think that `A.begin() - 1` is valid.

Comment: Just to clarify: The *random access iterator* requirements add the binary `-` operator used in the OP, but the decrementability and the validity of `--` is a consequence of *bidirectional iterator* requirements in general.

Answer (score 5):

It's *almost* safe if you are mindful of some exceptional cases:

`A.end()` gives you an iterator denoting the position just beyond the end of the `std::vector`. You should **not** attempt to dereference it.

If the vector has zero elements then `A.end() - 1` is **not** well-defined. In all other cases it is and you can indeed perform pointer arithmetic so long as you are in the container bounds. Note that the standard guarantees that the `std::vector` data are contiguous and packed in exactly the same way as an C++ array of the contains type. The only exception is `std::vector<bool>` which behaves differently due to a standards-specified tight packing specialisation. (Note well that`sizeof(bool)` is **not** guaranteed to have a particular value by the standard).

If I were you I'd use `A.rbegin()` to access the rightmost element and check the return value before proceeding and stick to the iterator formulation. It's all too easy to forget the `std::vector<bool>` specialisation.

Comment: I'm not sure about the `bool` case. Isn't this iterator--not pointer--arithmetics, like @Jarod42 pointed out? Shouldn't that make it entirely safe and well-defined also for `std::vector<bool>`?

Comment: If a `std::vector<bool>` has exactly 3 elements then I'm not convinced that `A.end() - 1` is defined if `sizeof(bool) == sizeof(int)`. I might be wrong though. But if you cast anything to `bool*` then you are certainly in trouble. Perhaps an overloaded operator on the `bool` reverse iterator takes care of this. Short answer: I don't know. I'm thinking of putting a bounty on this question.

Comment: If `std::vector<bool>::iterator` did act like you are saying, simple iteration over the vector would not work. As long as you are operating on iterators, `- 1` must move it one logical element, not `sizeof(bool)` bytes. I put some code on http://ideone.com/2pAiE1, and it works as I expect as long as the result of the subtraction is within the container. You should compile it with `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` (or equivalent for your compiler) to have it bark at you when you overstep the bounds.

Comment: But yes, if you toss out the iterator and use a `bool*` instead, you are certainly in trouble :)

Comment: @Magnus Hoff I've checked the source code for my STL (not definitive I know) and you are correct. I'll dig out the draft standard later. Luckly my answer holds though and I believe I've sufficiently cautioned against *pointer*, rather than *iterator* arithmetic.

Comment: The C++14 and C++17 standards, at least (I didn't check 20) state that `vector<bool>` meets all of the same requirements as every other `vector<T>` with the sole exception being that it does not have to meet *ContiguousContainer* requirements (*[vector.bool]* clause 2, *[vector.overview]* clause 2). Also; whether or not the container meets *ContiguousContainer* requirements doesn't impact the decrementability of `end()`; as long as its iterators meet *BidirectionalIterator* requirements, `--` is *supposed* to work. In theory.

Answer (score 4):

I realize this question is a bit old but I was directed here regarding `end() - 1`, and I found the existing answers and comments to be informative and reasonable, but unconvincing in lack of citations, and also I wasn't sure if they were specific to `vector`. So I dug up as much concrete information as I could to convince myself that the answers here were correct.

This post represents my research to confirm the answers, and is basically my notes, but I tried to make it as coherent as possible and I thought it might be useful. If anything here is off, corrections would be *greatly* appreciated.

---

### Restating The Answers

The **TL;DR** here is yes, the answers here are correct, not just for `vector`, but in the more general case as well:

If the container's iterator types satisfy [*BidirectionalIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator) (and therefore provide decrement operations), then the following will always be valid, for *any* container type, where `e` is initialized to the return value of `container.end()`:

- If `!container.empty()` then `--e` is valid.
- If `!container.empty()` then `++(--e) == container.end()` is true.

If the iterators also satisfy [*RandomAccessIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator), then these more general statements are valid:

- `e - n` and `e -= n` for any integer **n** in **[ 0, *container.size()* ]**
- `e + n` and `e += n` for any integer **n** in **[ *- container.size()* , 0 ]**

And so, the `vector` example in the OP is not only fine, as the other answers also state, but it's well-defined and guaranteed to be fine for any container type.

---

### Reasoning

So now here is the bit that I felt was missing. First, from the *Container* requirements:

> | expression | return type | semantics | conditions | complexity |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | `a.end()` | (const_)iterator | iterator to one past the last element of **a** |  | Constant |

This says "one past the last element". However, does this mean `end()` is decrementable? We need to be sure. The items below are  significant here and I've numbered them for reference:

1. [*Container*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container): The "`end()` returns one past the end of **a**" requirement mentioned above.
2. [*RandomAccessIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator): `i - n`, defined in terms of `-=`, no constraints given.
3. [*RandomAccessIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator): `r -= n`, defined in terms of `+=`, no constraints given.
4. [*RandomAccessIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator): `r += n`, defined in terms of `--r` for `n < 0`, no constraints given.
5. [*BidirectionalIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator): `--a`

   - Precondition: **a** is decrementable → there exists **b** such that `a == ++b`.
   - Postcondition: **a** is dereferenceable.
   - Postcondition: `--(++a) == a`
   - Postcondition: if `--a == --b` then `a == b`
   - Postcondition: `a` and `--a` are the same iterator instance.
6. [*BidirectionalIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator): **Notes:** "A bidirectional iterator does not have to be dereferenceable to be decrementable (in particular, the end iterator is not dereferenceable but is decrementable)".
7. [*Container*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container): States that `size()` is semantically equivalent to `std::distance(begin(), end())`
8. [`distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance): Returns the *number of increments* to get from `first` to `last`.

Breaking this down:

The precondition for (5) states that for `--a` to work, **a** *must be decrementable*, and goes on to define that an iterator **a** is decrementable if there exists a **b** such that `++ b == a`.

(1)'s "one past the end" language *seems to imply* that if **b** is an iterator to the last element in the container, then `++ b == end()`. More convincingly, though, (7) shows that `std::distance(begin(), end())` must work, and (8) therefore implies that the iterator returned by `begin()` must be able to be repeatedly incremented until it equals `end()`, which means that for a non-empty container, at some point there *must* exist a **b** such that `++ b == end()`.

Combining these two, then, shows that `end()` is always decrementable if `!empty()`, because there is always a **b** such that `++ b == end()` (otherwise `distance(begin(), end())` — and therefore `size()` — would not meet its semantic requirements), which is the definition of decrementability. Also note that (6) explicitly states that a decrementable iterator *need not be dereferenceable*, and has a note about the decrementability of the end iterator.

Furthermore, since `end()` is decrementable when `!empty()`, then (where `e` is initialized to the return value of `container.end()`):

- `-- e` is valid, from (5).
- `e += n` for `n <= 0` is valid, from (4).
- `e -= n` for `n >= 0` is valid, from (3).
- `e - n` for `n >= 0` is valid, from (2).
- Since `+=`, `-=`, and `-` (for sign of **n** indicated above) are all semantically defined in terms of repeatedly applying `--`, this constrains **n** to be within the container's size, since `begin()` is not decrementable (by definition of decrementability) and eventually the iterator must hit `begin()`.

Therefore the `- 1` in the OP is valid (from (2)) as long as there is at least 1 element before the iterator it's being applied to.

*Decrementability vs. dereferenceability*: Note that there is a difference. (6) points out that the concepts are separate. Decrementability implies that `--i` is valid, dereferenceability implies that `*i` and `i->` are valid. In the OP's `vector` example, while `end()` is decrementable, it is not dereferenceable ([`vector::end()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end) explicitly states this).

---

### Code

Oh, yeah, also I wrote [a test program](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9vc1sPOpyOasAp0s) just as a sanity check:

```
#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>
#include <version>
#if __has_include(<array>) && (__cplusplus >= 201103L)
#  include <array>
#  define HAVE_ARRAY 1
#endif
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <list>
#include <set> // + multiset
#include <map> // + multimap
#if __has_include(<span>) && (__cpp_lib_span >= 202002L)
#  include <span>
#  define HAVE_SPAN 1
#endif
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>

#if (__cpp_constexpr < 200704L)
#  define constexpr
#endif

using namespace std;

constexpr const int MAGIC = 42;

int extract (const int &v) {
    return v;
}

int extract (const pair<int,int> &v) {
    assert(v.first == v.second);
    return v.first;
}

template <typename C> struct decrementable_end_tester {
    C container;
    decrementable_end_tester ();
    void test () {
        printf("%s...\n", boost::core::demangle(typeid(C).name()).c_str());
        assert(!container.empty());
        {
            typename C::iterator b = container.begin();
            typename C::iterator e = container.end();
            assert(b == --e);
            assert(extract(*e) == MAGIC);
            assert(container.end() == ++e);
        }
        {
            typename C::iterator b = container.begin();
            typename C::iterator e = container.end(); 
            assert(e == ++b);
            assert(container.begin() == --b);
            assert(extract(*b) == MAGIC);
        }
    }
};

// i thought templating that would make initialization simpler but i'm not really
// that great with templates so i dunno if i got the most out of it:

template <typename C> decrementable_end_tester<C>::decrementable_end_tester () {
    container.insert(container.end(), MAGIC);
}

#if HAVE_ARRAY
template <> decrementable_end_tester<array<int,1> >::decrementable_end_tester () {
    container[0] = MAGIC;
}
#endif

#if HAVE_SPAN
static int span_buffer = ~MAGIC;
template <> decrementable_end_tester<span<int,1> >::decrementable_end_tester () 
    : container(&span_buffer, 1)
{
    container[0] = MAGIC;
}
#endif

template <> decrementable_end_tester<map<int,int> >::decrementable_end_tester () {
    container.insert(make_pair(MAGIC, MAGIC));
}

template <> decrementable_end_tester<multimap<int,int> >::decrementable_end_tester () {
    container.insert(make_pair(MAGIC, MAGIC));
}

int main () {
    // forward_list, unordered_([multi](set|map)) don't use bidirectional iterators.
#if HAVE_ARRAY
    decrementable_end_tester<array<int,1> >().test();
#endif
    decrementable_end_tester<vector<int> >().test();
    decrementable_end_tester<deque<int> >().test();
    decrementable_end_tester<list<int> >().test();
    decrementable_end_tester<set<int> >().test();
    decrementable_end_tester<multiset<int> >().test();
    decrementable_end_tester<map<int,int> >().test();
    decrementable_end_tester<multimap<int,int> >().test();
#if HAVE_SPAN
    decrementable_end_tester<span<int,1> >().test();
#endif
}
```

Should run without tripping any assertions.

---

I hope that was helpful. Pretty much all of that was me working to convince myself that `end() - 1` was indeed valid