# Decrementable requirements of general end iterators vs container `end()`

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, c++17, language-lawyer

I am working on a [*ReversibleContainer*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ReversibleContainer) and its associated [*LegacyRandomAccessIterators*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator). They wrap a pre-existing data structure that represents a directly-indexable collection of objects. I decided to allow the iterators to exist standalone, and to make default-constructed iterators represent the "end":

```
// constructs an iterator that provides a view of 'data'
the_iterator (thedata *data, difference_type index = 0);

// constructs an iterator representing the end
the_iterator ();
```

So I can do e.g.:

```
std::for_each(the_iterator(data), the_iterator(), ...);
```

The iterators do all the work. The container is pretty lightweight. I implemented the container's `begin()` and `end()` like this:

```
struct the_container {
    the_data *data; // <- object wrapped by this container
    the_iterator begin () { return the_iterator(data); }
    the_iterator end () { return the_iterator(); }
};
```

I've got it working just fine, but in testing I realized that I messed up and it does not meet the basic [*Container*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container) requirements because:

- As it turns out, for containers with bidirectional iterators, [`end()` is required to return a decrementable iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25928547/616460) when the container is non-empty, but
- My default-constructed end iterator doesn't store any information about any `thedata`, and so it can't be decremented because it isn't aware of what the "last element" of any particular collection is.

So I've got to fix the container now. The solution I'm thinking of is (let `data->number_of_items` contain the item count):

- Continue to allow default-constructed iterators to represent the "end".
- Also let `the_iterator(data, data->number_of_items)` represent the "end", in line with container requirements. This iterator would be decrementable.

Then the container would do:

```
struct the_container {
    the_data *data; // <- object wrapped by this container
    the_iterator begin () { return the_iterator(data, 0); }
    the_iterator end () { return the_iterator(data, data->number_of_items); }
};
```

Now, that's fine, and it satisfies all the *Container* requirements. However, I'm now left wondering if my default-constructed iterators are allowed to exist at all.

So, my question, then, is: **While *Container* puts decrementability requirements on the iterator that it returns from `end()`, are there similar requirements for iterators that just represent the "end" of some data but aren't involved with the container's `end()`?**

More formally, if:

- `j` is a bidirectional iterator
- `container.empty() == false`
- `( j == container.end() ) == true`

Then does `--j` need to be valid and need to end up pointing to the last element of the container? An example of that situation in my case is:

```
the_container container(data); // <- assume data->number_of_items > 0
the_iterator b = container.begin();
the_iterator e = container.end();
the_iterator j;

assert(container.empty() == false);
assert(e == j);
assert(distance(b, e) == distance(b, j));

-- e;  // <- this is required to be well-defined
-- j;  // <- but is this??
```

So, yeah, that's my question. I'm worried that maybe some implementation of something or other in e.g. `<algorithm>` might assume that one of my "end" iterators is decrementable, or that I'm breaking something subtle that I don't understand.

Comment: I hope this question makes sense; it was super hard to put into words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a frame challenge, what you have here is a sentinal.  A sentinal is something you can compare iterators to, but is not an iterator.

The motivating example is a type that when compared with a char pointer just checks if the dereference of the char pointer is null.  You can use this to write C-level "read string until null" while still using `for(:)` loops and the like.

The ranged based `for(:)` loop was augmented to allow begin and end to have distinct types to allow sentinals to exist and be maximally efficient.

Consider replacing your default constructed iterator trick with an end sentinal.  This doesn't work with many pre-ranges-v2 algorithms, but at least you are uwing tried and true patterns.

And no, I don't think your end iterator violates the rules.   As an example, iterators from two containers can have non sense `==` results under the standard.  Your end iterator can be treated as an iterator from another container with a predictable `==` behaviour.

Now, what happens when you pass it to an algorithm?  That probably makes your program ill-formed; the algorithm can detect what guarantees you give with traits, and your fake end iterator is not a valid bidirectional iterator into the same container as the begin iterator.

Comment: I never thought of the two-different-container thing. That's convincing on its own. I looked through a [C++17 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) and found, in **[forward.iterators]** (§27.2.5), ¶2, a constraint that the domain of `==` for forward iterators is iterators in the same sequence. Then, it notes that all value initialized iterators must compare equal to eachother and behave like end-of-sequence iterators to the same empty sequence (meaning same as each other, but different than any other sequence). So no matter what, it's outside `==`'s domain.

Comment: (Note: somewhere earlier, I forget where, there is a definition that states that "value initialized" includes default-constructed.)

Answer (score 1):

> Then does --j need to be valid and need to end up pointing to the last element of the container?

For any bidirectional iterator, `--j` must be well defined as long as its pre-conditions are satisfied. And the pre-condition is that there exists another iterator `s` for which `j == ++s`. And for your container the iterator to the last valid element is such iterator

As such, I don't believe that your iterator would satisfy the requirements of a bidirectional iterator and thus the container would not be reversible.

If you want to define a sentinel for a bidirectional iterator, it can be done by using a separate type so that iterator requirements won't apply to it. There is a caveat though that most standard algorithms don't support separate iterator and sentinel types. `std::ranges` algorithms do.

Alternatively, you could specify that the default initialised iterator is *singular* i.e. it isn't associated with any container. In such case `-- j` wouldn't have any requirements (nor would `j == e`). But then `b, j` wouldn't be a valid range and you still wouldn't be allowed to pass such pair into standard algorithms.

Comment: So, in other words, as long as `end()` returns that default-constructed iterator (which does not meet bidirectional requirements), then the container fails to meet reversible requirements. So, while I can fix `end()` to return a satisfactory iterator (and thus fix the broken reversible container), I still run into trouble if I pass the standalone containerless default-constructed iterator to algorithms and such that require the parameter to be a bidirectional iterator. Otoh, though, I'm at least OK when only forward iterators are required. Right?

Comment: @JasonC As long as youccorrectly specify that the iterator is not a bidirectional iterator. An algorithm that requires one iterator category may specialise their behaviour based on the category of the given iterator.